# Does the the key used to encrypt in a ransomware attack reside on the target computer for at least some time?

Tags: encryption, key-management, asymmetric, ransomware

My understanding is that a ransomware uses the target computer's resources to encrypt files. So does that mean that the key used for encryption resides on the target computer for at least some time? I am assuming that symmetric encryption is used to encrypt.
Are asymmetric encryption methods also used in ransomware attacks?

Comment: Hi and welcome on Stack Exchange. This is a very interesting question, but I am sure it's already covered on this site. Expect to have it marked as duplicate.

Comment: You are correct. The answer I was after is the second post on this question. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/111733/how-does-ransomware-work

Comment: I agree with the dupe